# pass the arguments in a json file

Tags: json, gitlab, gitlab-ci, packages.json

I need to pass the branch name in git-dependencies as a parameter. But in my `packages.json`, I am unable to do so. The structure looks something like following:

```
{
    "servers" : [
            ...
             ],
    "target" : "apps",
    "git" : {
            "git-remote" : "..."
        },
    "source" : {
            "git-dependencies-path": "../",
            "source-packages-path" : "../"
           },
    "wiki" : {
            "local-wiki-path" : "../",
            "git-wiki-path" : ""
         },
        "git-dependencies" : [  {"repository" : "application/app1", "branch" : "development", "source-packages" : [ "."]}, //the branch name I want to parameterize}],
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting the mainstay of the final `packages.json` in a `.template` and simply appending the branch name and closing parens, etc at ci runtime.
You can keep your 'true' `package.json` in git and just overwrite it then too.

*package.json.template*:

```
{
    "servers" : [
            ...
             ],
    "target" : "apps",
    "git" : {
            "git-remote" : "..."
        },
    "source" : {
            "git-dependencies-path": "../",
            "source-packages-path" : "../"
           },
    "wiki" : {
            "local-wiki-path" : "../",
            "git-wiki-path" : ""
         },
        "git-dependencies" : [  {"repository" : "application/app1", "branch" : "development", "source-packages" : [ "
```

*gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
- before_script: |
    cp packages.json.template packages.json
    echo "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" >> packages.json
    echo '"]},}' >> packages.json
```

If you have more involved needs for filling the `packages.json` I'd suggest using a python script with a [string template](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#template-strings) or [jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Comment: good thing, I got to try it both the ways in the past few months. I did overwrite the packages.json using sed for it to take the branch name. And in another circumstance, I had to parse this JSON to install a dependency, a python script only to parse the JSON helped. Thank you for your answer!